# How do I receive an external app's broadcast metadata?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, spotify

I am trying to add a feature to my app which receives broadcast data/intent-actions from Spotify and does something with that data. However, I am not sure how to proceed. I've been able to piece together the following code with the help of previous questions, however those questions do not go into detail on **how to actually initiate the reception of data**. I have a BroadCast Receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.queuechanged"/>
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

I have a BroadCast Receiver class (all set up):

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final class BroadcastTypes {
        static final String SPOTIFY_PACKAGE = "com.spotify.music";
        static final String PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".playbackstatechanged";
        static final String METADATA_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".metadatachanged";
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L);
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED)) {

            String trackId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
            String artistName = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String albumName = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String trackName = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            int trackLengthInSec = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);

            //send data to main class?

        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED)) {

           boolean playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
            int positionInMs = intent.getIntExtra("playbackPosition", 0);

            //send data to main class?
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the following methods in my main activity:

```
public void mute(AudioManager audioManager){

    audioManager.setStreamMute(am.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);

}

public void unMute(AudioManager audioManager){

    audioManager.setStreamMute(am.STREAM_SYSTEM,false);

}
```

which I want to call after receiving and analyzing the BroadCast data from my Receiver class.

**In Summary:**

> So now I am not sure how I can actually start the acquisition of data from Spotify in my main activity (whether I have to manually "call" my receiver, or whether it will automatically listen for Broadcasts in the background while my main Activity is running).

A detailed explanation would be very much appreciated and will be rewarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering a Receiver class statically via the manifest is all that is required. The application will automatically listen for the intent actions defined in the receivers intent-filter e.g.

On receiving one of the specified actions the application will automatically spin up a background thread to run the onReceive method.

As far as I can tell you have all the required pieces setup for static receiver registration.

But beware as of Android 3.1 the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu

Also ensure Spotify has media notifications enabled: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-media-notifications/#enabling-media-notifications